# Failed to compare two elements in the array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
private SortedList<ToolStripMenuItem, Form> forms = new SortedList<ToolStripMenuItem, Form>();                

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   formsAdd(menuCommandPrompt, new CommandPrompt());
   formsAdd(menuLogScreen, new LogScreen()); //Error
}

private void formsAdd(ToolStripMenuItem item, Form form)
{
   forms.Add(item, form); //Failed to compare two elements in the array.
   form.Tag = this;
   form.Owner = this;
}
```

I can't get that why it throws error. Error occurs on second line of form load event.

formsAdd method simply adds form and toolstip element to the array(forms) and sets tag and owner of form to this. On second call of function, it throws an error.

```
CommandPrompt, LogScreen /* are */ Form //s
menuCommandPrompt, menuLogScreen /* are */ ToolStripMenuItem //s
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Exception detail, please. It looks like you created a sorted list of ToolStripMenuItem but haven't provided a way to compare them, which makes sorting difficult.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a `SortedList`, but `ToolStripMenuItem` does not implement `IComparable`, so the list does not know how to sort them.

If you don't need to have the items sorted, you can use a list of `Tuple`s or a `Dictionary`, depending on what exactly do you want to do.

If you want to have them sorted, you need use [the overload of `SortedLists`'s constructor that takes `IComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.-ctor#System_Collections_Generic_SortedList_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__). That means you have to implement that interface in some way.

Comment: It seems I have a lot of works to do.. Why am I using this method is I simply created a function that implements all my ToolStripMenuItem's click events. I get sender stuff and then open the form related to MenuItem.

Comment: The using `Dictionary` is probably the best thing to do.

Comment: For some reason I have to get the SortedList's index by index's value. It's not possible in Directories. (Think so)

Answer (score 2):

Do both your object types implement IComparable? This is a must for the sorted list to compare the objects it is adding to the array.

Comment: I don't know about IComparable thing... =D And Don't know how I will handle this stuff.

Comment: Only key objects need to implement `IComparable`. And the question states that the key is [`ToolStripMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx), which does not implement it.

Comment: @svick yea I typed in haste on a train ride with a slow mobile connection. Thanks for posting a more complete answer.